C++ DLL - Prevent Access To Items After Compilation?
I really don't like the idea of putting lots of effort into carefully developing & designing a C++ library only for it to be the case that the only thing stopping those who link the DLL from accessing data they shouldn't be accessing even accidentally being the hand-written access modifiers provided in the .h files that go along with the DLL.
What solutions can I consider for recreating the concept of an access modifier after the DLL has been compiled that can't be changed as simply as re-writing access modifiers in the .h files packed-in with distribution versions of the DLL?
A solution I've considered but don't fully understand is having __declspec(dllexport) specified only on public API methods, classes, etc. such that rewriting some item in an .h file to become public when it is supposed to be private won't matter since the LIB file won't be populated with that item and therefore it cannot be used by those who link the DLL. I don't fully understand this solution like I said and therefore cannot say with confidence if this will be an answer to my question (seems to be just a simpler version of a .def file which is a file that was explained to me yesterday) but I just wanted to bring up my awareness of it, if you think it'd work just let me know before I get invested into bloating an existing library with it only to find out it doesn't work at all (I suppose I should just set up an MRE but now I'm just rambling).

You could also use PIMPL and avoid exposing the private implementation in the header. This is what I do in my code.

public and private access specifiers are only there for the C++ compiler and have no bearing on visibility or accessibility in a library . Hiding symbols from the export table is slightly better, but many reverse engineering tools don't even bother with that and are able to isolate functions from the DLL text segment. Assume that any code you put into a DLL is public knowledge from the moment you publish it.

I think what you are looking for is not private but a mechanism that prevents users of a lib to access parts of the lib. private isnt really that, so its somewhat confusing that you describe what you want in terms of private

@drescherjm Yes actually I was told about PIMPL in a previous question, I'm getting really lost in the weeds of trying to turn an existing project into a library the last few days but now that I think about it, that MIGHT work. If I have the implementation class forward-delcared in a .h then the defintion of the entire class in some .cpp file then those who link the DLL don't even have the ability to alter signatures on the implementation class since those signatures were compiled away in a .cpp file they won't have access to, right?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you're right, i'm sorry for the confusion, i just didn't want the title of the question to be too long-winded.

i mean: Describe what you want. That  private is not doing what you want can make a footnote. Currently you say "I want private but not quite, I want something that works like private just that it works differently than private" .... I am exaggerating to get the point across ;)

@Botje I do get that fundamentally I'm kind of up the creek since the concept of access modifiers means nothing to compiled code, I just think it's crazy how easy it is to destroy careful design work that goes into a C++ library. I've had experience making C# libraries before and whilst I don't understand the nitty-gritty, I do understand that one of the perks of C# being higher level than C++ is that C# can have the internal keyword to do pretty much exactly what I want in a library here.

Not so much "higher level" as "built on a VM that enforces access control" as opposed to "built on a language where reading and writing arbitrary memory is an inalienable right"

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I've altered the question title and a part of the question itself to try and more directly address what I'm really asking, however IDK if I did a good job of that.

@Botje Now that's interesting you bring that up, I did not fundamentally understand that C# was executing in a more controlled environment than C++ though I suppose it makes implicit sense. That's why C# as a language can have internal and C++ cannot since every time C# code runs it is running within an environment that is aware of what an access modifier is despite being pre-compiled code whereas access modifiers in C++ are more of a convention and design choice that completely disappears once compiled. Another user suggested PIMPL and I think that might be what I'm looking for.

I didn't continue commenting about PIMPL because I agree with @Botje specifically about the part of Reverse Engineering. While using PIMPL hides the implementation details from the public API it doesn't prevent a determined hacker from gaining access. It really depends on who and what you are trying to prevent.

There's a saying, "C++ guards against Murphy, not Machiavelli". C++ access control is meant to make it easier for honest people to use the library as designed, and harder to use it incorrectly. It does nothing to prevent people from misusing it intentionally.

Even the .NET restrictions are not hardened against a sufficiently motivated consumer using reflection to access private items.  They're effectively little different from C++ private (which will still require serious, non-standard gymnastics to get around).

As mentioned by you and others in the comments, one of the main motivations behind the PIMPL pattern is exactly to solve the problem you describe.
A simplified implementation might look like this :
// 'Foo.h'
// Forward declare FooImpl here, but no definition in public header !
// What it is or does is not accessible to the user of this header.
class FooImpl; 

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  // bar() works some magic that we don't want to leak to the outside.
  int bar();

private:
  FooImpl* pImpl;

};


// 'Foo.cpp'
#include Foo.h

// Define FooImpl here or in a separate and private (not distributed) header,
// so that it won't be visible to consumers of this lib.
class FooImpl
{
public:
  void FooImpl(){};

  int bar()
  {     
      return someMagic;
  };

private:
  int someMagic{42};

};

void Foo::Foo()
{
  pImpl = new FooImpl{};
}

void Foo::~Foo()
{
  delete pImpl;
}

int Foo::bar()
{
  return pImpl->bar();
}


In essence, only the external interface of the class Foo remains visible in its header, the functions and definitions the consumer needs to actually use the class.
All implementation details (including private functions and member variables) are hidden under a second layer, which is the FooImpl class.
Note that while this will hide implementation details for users of your library, it is of course not a security measure against de-compilation or other such hacker tools in any sense.

Thank you for the tailored breakdown of PIMPL! My existing attempts to implement PIMPL looked pretty similar, however I am a bit of a C++ novice I admit and I have to wonder why all examples of PIMPL I see have the FooImpl member variable as private with wrappers to everything in FooImpl defined in Foo. Wouldn't it make more sense to make the FooImpl member public at that point? Or is it that because those who link the DLL don't know what a FooImpl is beyond declaration that trying to access FooImpl members/methods in those who link the DLL won't compile?

Also, I ran out of comment space to say this, but protection against (specifically accidental) misuse is all I'm after, if someone were to intentionally try and hack the DLL then anything going wrong is their own fault as far as I'm concerned.

It's because of 2 reasons I can think of at this time. FooImpl isn't exported from the dll and also normal users will not be able to know what members are part of FooImpl or its structure without someone spending time to reverse engineer your dll.

@drescherjm Oh okay then, that makes sense, I figured it'd be something like that.

@SpringE.Thing: The impl pointer should be private to mark it as not designed to be accessed from the outside. It could not be used from the outside anyway, because its definition is not visible - again by design. Its all to tell the user "this is all implementation detail, do not worry about it." (hence the name, ofc).
